# ggplot geom_tile overlay plot with points

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
severity <- c("Major","Serious","Minor","Negligible")
probability <- c("Highly Probable","Probable","Possible","Remote","Unlikely","Impossible")
df <- expand.grid(x=severity,y=probability)
df$x <- factor(df$x, levels=rev(unique(df$x)))
df$y <- factor(df$y, levels=rev(unique(df$y)))
df$color <- c(1,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,3,3,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)

ggplot(df,aes(x,y,fill=factor(color)))+
geom_tile(color="black")+
scale_fill_manual(guide="none",values=c("red","yellow","green"))+
scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0))+scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0))+
labs(x="",y="")
```

Produces a risk assesssment score card chart.  I want to add points by using a csv file by adding a record.  Each record has 3 fields, a item name, x, and y coordinate. x= severity and y = probability.

```
   da <- data.frame(list(name=c("ENVIRONMENTAL","COSTS","SUPPLY","HEALTH"),
                    severity=c("Major","Serious","Minor","Serious"),
                    probability=c("Probable","Possible","Probable","Unlikely")))
da
           name severity probability
1 ENVIRONMENTAL    Major    Probable
2         COSTS  Serious    Possible
3        SUPPLY    Minor    Probable
4        HEALTH  Serious    Unlikely

> p1 <- p + data.frame(da, aes(severity, probability)) + geom_point()
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ""uneval"" to a data.frame
> 

> d <- data.frame(list(name=c("ENVIRONMENTAL","COSTS","SUPPLY","HEALTH"),
    severity=c(2,3,4,1),probability=c(3,5,4,6)))
> d
           name severity probability
1 ENVIRONMENTAL        2           3
2         COSTS        3           5
3        SUPPLY        4           4
4        HEALTH        1           6
> ggplot(d,x=severity, y=probability)+ geom_point()
Error in exists(name, envir = env, mode = mode) : 
  argument "env" is missing, with no default
```

How can I add points to the ggplot / geom_tile graph?

Comment: unless I'm mistaken, `data.frame(list(...))` is equivalent to `data.frame(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add a data.frame to a plot (not like that, at least...). What you can do is add a new layer, `geom_point()`, and specify the data.frame it comes from. To make things work, you should have the columns from any aesthetics you still want to use (here, `x` and `y`) have the same names in both data.frames.

```
# It's better practice to modify your data
# then to convert to factor within the plot
df$color <- factor(c(1,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,3,3,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3))

# get some meaningful names, that match da and d
names(df)[1:2] <- c("severity", "probability")


p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = severity, y = probability)) +
    # moved fill to the geom_tile layer, because it's only used there
    geom_tile(color = "black", aes(fill = color)) + 
    scale_fill_manual(guide = "none", values = c("red", "yellow", "green")) +
    scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
    scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
    labs(x = "", y = "")
    # alsonoticehowaddingspacesmakesiteasiertoread

# Using the same column names? Yup! Now it's this easy:
p + geom_point(data = da) +
    geom_point(data = d, color = "dodgerblue4")
```

Comment: Since thank you are not perferred in comments.  This is the final plot

Comment: p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = severity, y = probability)) +
+     # moved fill to the geom_tile layer, because it's only used there
+     geom_tile(color = "black", aes(fill = color)) + 
+     scale_fill_manual(guide = "none", values = c("red", "yellow", "green")) +
+     scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
+     scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
+     labs(x = "Severity", y = "Probability")                                                        p2 <- p1+ geom_text(data=d, mapping=aes(severity, probability, label=name), size=5, vjust= 2)  # I like